# How to program showDialogMessage?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I just programmed an interface about user registration. For delete user part, when i click delete button, the program will show a box asking "are you sure about deleting the user?" If i choose yes, then how can i program to show a showDialogMessage to tell the user the user has been deleted?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: What GUI library? What context? This is a somewhat uninformative question, and you need to tell us the details.

Comment: it seems the website didn't show how to program to connect two dialog box together, like show message dialog box after the user makes a choice in the confirm dialog box.

Comment: Again what library? Swing? AWT? Android? Something else entirely? -1 until you fix this question.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe i didn't explain well. Im not a english speaker. I was using Netbeans to make a interface for user registration.

Comment: Java netbeans swing GUI builder.@HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: [tag:swing] tag added.

Answer (score 2):

Just pitching here, but if you are using swing, look into [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) especially the `showMessageDialog` methods.

Answer (score 2):

`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)`  This is for getting confirmation from user.

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)` this is for showing that the user has been deleted.

Since your question is incomplete, answering in the contrast of Swing

`int i=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure about deleting the user?");`

`if(i==0) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User deleted");`

Confirmation box return `0` if chosen is `yes`, `1` if chosen is `no` and `2` if chosen is `cancel`

Go through [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) you will get better idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! that helps a lot. Sorry about my bad expression.

Comment: @ShuaiZhang If u found it useful, tick this answer as correct one. And also next time when u ask questions explain specifically about every detail. Good luck.